# How to get a counter on specific values on JSON file with JS?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, lodash

I have the following JSON:

**/api/v1/volumes:**

```
[
  {
    "id": "vol1",
    "status": "UP",
    "sto": "sto1",
    "statusTime": 1558525963000,
    "resources": {
      "disk": 20000000
    },
    "used_resources": {
      "disk": 15000000
    },
    "lastUpdated": "2019-05-28T20:15:44.585Z"
  },
  {
    "id": "vol2",
    "status": "UP",
    "sto": "sto1",
    "statusTime": 1558525963000,
    "resources": {
      "disk": 50000000
    },
    "used_resources": {
      "disk": 28000000
    },
    "lastUpdated": "2019-05-28T20:15:44.585Z"
  }
]
```

And I would like to fetch the data to process it and get a counter with the total space of the `used_resources.disk` fields over all the volumes, and also to get the top 5 largest volumes with used space.

I was thinking about something like this:

```
let _volumes = {
   lastUpdated: 0,
   results: []
}

export function getCapacityByVolumes() {
  if(_volumes.results.length && Date.now() - _volumes.lastUpdated < 1000 * 60) {
    return Promise.resolve(_volumes)
  }
  return fetch('/api/v1/volumes', {
    credentials: 'same-origin'
  })
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(result => {
      let volumes = result.map(volume => {
        volume.resources = chain(volume.id)
          .groupBy('sto')
          .values()
          .reduce((memo, volume) => {
            return {
               resources: {
                 disk: (memo.resources.disk || 0) + volume.resources.disk
               },
               used_resources: {
                 disk: (memo.used_resources.disk || 0) + volume.used_resources.disk
               }
            }
       }, { resources: {}, used_resources: {}})
       .value()

     volume.largestDisk = chain(volume.id)
        .values()
        .sortBy(vol => vol.used_resources.disk)
        .reverse()
        .take(5)
        .value()

     return volumes
  })
  .value()

  _volumes = {
       results: volumes,
       lastUpdated: result.lastUpdated
  }
  _lastUpdated = Date.now()
  return _volumes
 })
}
```

But... unfortunately this isn't working at all :(, I think that maybe I'm missing something on the chain or map thing, any ideas?

Regarding the output, I'm looking to get the `total disk` and the `total used disk` group by `sto`, so I need to iterate over all the volumes (id).

for consuming the get function im using this:

```
class Capacity extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {capacity: {}, lastUpdated: null, volumes: []}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getCapacityByVolumes()
    .then(result => {
      this.setState({capacity: result.volumes, lastUpdated: result.lastUpdated})
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="breadcrumbs">
          <Link to={ '/capacity' } className="crumb">Capacity Dashboard</Link>
        </div>

        <h1 className="m0">Capacity</h1>
        <div>
        {
          chain(this.state.capacity).mapValues((data, id) => {
            return (
              <div key={id}>
                <h2 className="m0">{id.toUpperCase()}</h2>
                <div className="flex flex-wrap">
                  <div className="col col-4 pr3">
                    <h4>Storage Resources</h4>
                    <div className="mb2">
                      Disk capacity
                      <div className="meta-data right">
                        <span className="value">{data.used_resources.disk}</span> used
                        <span className="separator m1">+</span>
                        <span className="value">{data.resources.disk - data.used_resources.disk}</span> available
                        <span className="separator m1">=</span>
                        <span className="value">{data.resources.disk}</span> total
                      </div>
                      <div className="clearfix"></div>
                      <Range
                        value={data.used_resources.disk}
                        total={data.resources.disk} />
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div className="col col-4 pr3">
                    <h4>Top 5 Volumes with highest disk</h4>
                    <table className="volumes-table">
                      <tbody className="h6">
                        <tr>
                          <th>Volume</th>
                          <th>disk</th>
                        </tr>
                        {
                          data.largestDisk.map(volume => {
                            return (
                              <tr key={volume.id}>
                                <td><Link to={ '/volumes/' + volume.id }>{volume.id}</Link></td>
                                <td>{formatMB(volume.resources.disk)}</td>
                              </tr>
                            )
                          })
                        }
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <div className="clearfix"></div>
                <hr />
              </div>
            )
          })
          .values()
          .value()
        }
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Capacity
```

and I'm getting the following error:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'dedicated' of undefined`

Comment: Hello! In what manner is it "not working at all": Are you getting an error? If so, please edit your question to include it. Is the output not what you're expecting? If so, please edit your question to add both the expected output, and the actual output. Also, what library are you using to get the `chain` function and then `.groupBy`, `.sortBy`, and `.take` methods? Could you please either tag your question with that library, or link to the function definitions somewhere your question?

Comment: thanks a lot for the response pete, regarding the functions `chain`, `.groupBy`, and the rest, I'm using `lodash`. I'm not with my computer right now to test it again, I will upload that asap. thanks!

Comment: so, how can I change it to reflect the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're returning `volumes` (instead of `volume`) in the `.map` call.
Since `volumes` is `undefined` there, I suspect that's part of the problem.

The other problem I see is with the error you're getting:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'dedicated' of undefined

Assuming the above advice returns a defined value for the promise, there is no property called `dedicated` in any code you've posted, so you may still wind up with an `undefined` value where you don't want one.

See comments:

```js
export function getCapacityByVolumes() {
    if(_volumes.results.length && Date.now() - _volumes.lastUpdated < 1000 * 60) {
        return Promise.resolve(_volumes)
    }

    return fetch('/api/v1/volumes', {
        credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(result => {
        let volumes = result.map(volume => {
            volume.resources = chain(volume.id)
                .groupBy('sto')
                .values()
                .reduce((memo, volume) => {
                    return {
                        resources: {
                        disk: (memo.resources.disk || 0) + volume.resources.disk
                       },
                       used_resources: {
                         disk: (memo.used_resources.disk || 0) + volume.used_resources.disk
                       }
                    }
                }, { resources: {}, used_resources: {}})
                .value()

            volume.largestDisk = chain(volume.id)
                .values()
                .sortBy(vol => vol.used_resources.disk)
                .reverse()
                .take(5)
                .value()

            return volumes // <-- `volumes` is not defined. perhaps you meant `volume`?
        })
        .value()

        _volumes = {
            results: volumes,
            lastUpdated: result.lastUpdated
        }

        _lastUpdated = Date.now() // not sure where this is defined.

        return _volumes
    })
}
```